# Send from Gmail "plus" (person+something@gmail.com) address in Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, catalina, gmail

I have a gmail account in Mail.app, example@gmail.com.

How can I send mail from Mail.app using the example+two@gmail.com From address, instead of the example@gmail.com From address?

Looking through all Mail preferences and System Preferences > Internet Accounts I don't see how. Probably there's some workaround though.

Comment: You have to use an alias.  See this help document:  https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-email-aliases-mlhlp1205/13.0/mac/10.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an email alias.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-email-aliases-mlhlp1205/13.0/mac/10.15

> ## Create or change an alias
>
> 1. In the Mail app on your Mac, choose Mail > Preferences, then click Accounts.
> 2. Select an account, then click Account Information.
> 3. Click the Email Address pop-up menu, choose Edit Email Addresses, then do one of the following:
>
>    - *Add an alias*: Click the Add button +, then enter a name and email address.
>
> ## Send an email from an alias
>
> 1. In the Mail app on your Mac, move the pointer over the From field in a message you’re writing.
> 2. Click the pop-up menu that appears, then choose an email alias.